# The given key was not present in the dictionary - error and warnings

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, blend

I'm making an app in WPF and blend and all of a sudden I get those errors and can't see the app design

[image: example screenshot]

when I press on the error its takes me to the XAML and show me that 'Window' is not good

On the other side, I can run the app with no problems

thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm going to go with "How do I fix it?"

Comment: We DO need to see your XAML though to be able to offer any help.

Comment: the XAML very long..you need all of it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've got a mismatch between target architectures. Try setting your build to any CPU or failing that x86. It looks like your blend environment has been installed in x86 for where it picks up the interactivity dlls.

Comment: Where you select debug/release in the toolbar you should have configure. In there you can select platforms for build

Comment: After rebuild all the warnings go away so thanks for that!

But I still get the error and cant see the design of the app

Comment: Well at least it isn't a symptom of the build. Next thing would be missing named resources. You can try commenting out your XAML and dropping it back in section by section till you narrow it down. Line 1 col 2 doesn't really point to a cause

Comment: even with no xaml content?

Comment: I'm thinking the only remaining possibility is a fault with the project itself. If your XAML is empty,  then check your app.xaml for anything that might be a bad reference such as a resource key that doesn't exist. Beyond that I am stumped without having the solution to look at

Comment: can't find the problem :/